# Uncaught Error: [Immer] An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or* modify the draft

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

Im using redux-toolkit and i'm trying to update an array of posts such that when the user clicks the remove button it sends the post object (which has {id, description, imageLink}, to the reducer and removes that object from the state array, returning the updated array.

I have this button that calls the dispatch method on click

```
<button className='remove-button' onClick={() => dispatch(removePost(post))}>Remove</button>
```

The format of the post looks like this

```
{id: 1, description: 'some-description', imageLink: 'some-link.jpg'}
```

here is the state array

```
posts = [
  {
    id: 0,
    description: "A-description",
    imageLink:  "a-link.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    description: "some-description",
    imageLink: "some-link.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: "another-description",
    imageLink: "another-link.jpg",
  }
]
```

and finally here is the code in my reducer

```
export const postSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState: MyPosts,
  reducers: {
    removePost: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload);
  

     for(var i = 0; i < state.length; i++){
        if(JSON.stringify(state[i]) == JSON.stringify(action.payload)){
        
            return [...state.splice(i, 1)]
        
        }
     }
  
    },
    addPost: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload);

      return [...state, action.payload];
    },
  },
 });
```

the addPost reducer works fine but for some reason I cannot remove a post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see my other provided answer solved the problem with the immer error, but still is insuficient.

You probably want something like this:

```
removePost: (state, action) => state.filter(i => JSON.stringify(state[i]) != JSON.stringify(action.payload));
```

Comment: This helped immensely! although your logic was slightly off so I edited it a bit, but filter was definitely the way to go. the edit I mead was changing JSON.stringify(state[i]) to JSON.stringify(i). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

On line

```
return [...state.splice(i, 1)]
```

you are returning the new state. But also, you are changing the current state with the `splice` method call. Use `slice` instead, because that way your `removePost` method wont change the state variable, it will only return the new state.

The code should be

```
return [...state.slice(i, 1)]
```

Comment: I tried using [...state.slice(i, 1)], and [...state.slice(i, i+1)] but it ends up either deleting everything in the array, or everything except the one I want. maybe its the logic i'm using? I thought slice takes: slice(start, end)